# Error in parameter that i use in update command in sqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I use below code :

**.aspx**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:Con %>" runat="server" 
        SelectCommand="select * from DorePayvar" OnSelecting="selecting" 
        UpdateCommand="update DorePayvar set Name=@name" OnUpdating="SqlDataSource1_Updating">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="name" DefaultValue="Sajjad" />
        </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**.cs**

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Command.Parameters["name"].Value = "bvhjbjh";   
    }
```

but when i press update button occur below error

> An SqlParameter with ParameterName 'name' is not contained by this
>   SqlParameterCollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the @ symbol.
The following should work :

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["@name"].Value = "bvhjbjh";   
}
```

For more information on using parameters with sqldatasource [check this out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that there is not a parameter in your parameter list with the name "name".

Try:

```
e.Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("name", "bvhjbjh"));
```